# Failing to run C# process as different user

Tags: c#, .net, impersonation

I'm trying to run `djoin.exe` tool with `System.Diagnostics.Process` from a C# service using a different user (not as the service user).

The process returns code `-1073741502`.

In the event log I can see:

> Application popup: djoin.exe - Application Error : The application was
>   unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click OK to close the
>   application.

No stderr or stdout.

Here is the process configurations I used:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    Arguments = "/Provision /Domain domain.com /Machine PC12 /SaveFile NUL /printblob",
    WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
    FileName = "djoin.exe"
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    CreateNoWindow =true,
    Domain = "domain.com",
    UserName = "other-user",
    Password = "***"
};

if (username!=null)
{
    startInfo.Domain = domain;
    startInfo.UserName = username;
    startInfo.Password = ToSecureString(password);
}

p = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };
p.Start();
```

When using the `RUNAS` command, everything works fine.

What is the problem?

Comment: What version of Windows is this?  And, does you app have elevated privileges?

Comment: Windows 2008 server R2. it's a service. what do you mean elevated privileges?

Comment: The DllMain() entrypoint of one of the DLLs used by that program returned FALSE.  It is unhappy, you don't really know why unless it left a message in the application event log.  Not good odds you'll find one.  You have not enough knobs to tweak, although you definitely ought to try setting LoadUserProfile to *true*.  Contact the author or owner of the app for help.

Comment: @HansPassant djoin appears to be a standard "built-in" utility, part of Windows Server http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff793312.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is a permissions issue. This can either be at the folder level of where the exe is located, or to do with the user that the process is running under.

To diagnose this, you can first go to the folder where the exe is located. Then right click and set the permissions to "everyone" with full control. Then try to run again and see if you get the same message.

Also when you run Visual studio, at the start, right click and run as administrator. I take it from your comment that this works OK, leading me to believe it is in fact permission related. e.g. Are the different users in the same domain? Once you work out the permissions of the folder where the applcation lives, create an account with permission on that folder and then have whatever process schedules/runs the exe to execute under that account.

Update - the comments above prompted another idea, you could use system.diagnostics to write eventlog entries at each point of the code, to help determine what is going wrong. Another tool that may be of use if WinDBG to get more info about what is throwing that exception.